# Flutter : Radio button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to turn my three buttons to radio button , so When you click on any of them, the border color and background color are changed , like the one in the middle
[image]

my button code

```
Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  height: 65,
                                  width: 350,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      Text('1 WEEK' , style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),),
                                      Row(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: [
                                          Text('2.99' , style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),),
                                          Text('/Week' , style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 11,
                                            color: Colors.white60,
                                          ),),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        width: 25,
                                        height: 25,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                          border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            width: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
**Radiobuttonwidget**

```
  //this array help us to manage the state of radio button.
var ischecked = [true, false, false];

class MyRadioButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyRadioButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyRadioButton> createState() => _MyRadioButtonState();
}

class _MyRadioButtonState extends State<MyRadioButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 16),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                ischecked[0]=true;
                ischecked[1]=false;
                ischecked[2]=false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ischecked[0]?Colors.lightGreen:Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              height: 65,
              // width: 100,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      '1 WEEK',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '2.99',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/Week',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ischecked[0]?Colors.red:Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 16),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                ischecked[1]=true;
                ischecked[0]=false;
                ischecked[2]=false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ischecked[1]?Colors.lightGreen:Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              height: 65,
              // width: 100,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      '1 WEEK',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '2.99',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/Week',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ischecked[1]?Colors.red:Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 16),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                ischecked[0]=false;
                ischecked[2]=true;
                ischecked[1]=false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ischecked[2]?Colors.lightGreen:Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              height: 65,
              // width: 100,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      '1 WEEK',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '2.99',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/Week',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ischecked[2]?Colors.red:Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**SAmpleCode** [Dartpad live](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d0b9977c219e9cdfc637562629415ff2)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [MyRadioButton()],
      ),

      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

var ischecked = [true, false, false];

class MyRadioButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyRadioButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyRadioButton> createState() => _MyRadioButtonState();
}

class _MyRadioButtonState extends State<MyRadioButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 16),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                ischecked[0]=true;
                ischecked[1]=false;
                ischecked[2]=false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ischecked[0]?Colors.lightGreen:Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              height: 65,
              // width: 100,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      '1 WEEK',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '2.99',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/Week',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ischecked[0]?Colors.red:Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 16),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                ischecked[1]=true;
                ischecked[0]=false;
                ischecked[2]=false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ischecked[1]?Colors.lightGreen:Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              height: 65,
              // width: 100,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      '1 WEEK',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '2.99',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/Week',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ischecked[1]?Colors.red:Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 16),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                ischecked[0]=false;
                ischecked[2]=true;
                ischecked[1]=false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ischecked[2]?Colors.lightGreen:Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              height: 65,
              // width: 100,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      '1 WEEK',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '2.99',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/Week',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ischecked[2]?Colors.red:Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have a problem if you can help me , iam using Getx so i created controlled   `  var ischecked = [true, false, false].obs;


  void ontap1(){
    ischecked.value[0]=true;
    ischecked.value[1]=false;
    ischecked.value[2]=false;
  }
  void ontap2(){
    ischecked.value[1]=true;
    ischecked.value[0]=false;
    ischecked.value[2]=false;
  }
  void ontap3(){
    ischecked.value[0]=false;
    ischecked.value[2]=true;
    ischecked.value[1]=false;
  }
`
but it tells me (type 'List<bool>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<bool>' of 'function result')

Comment: ` RxList<bool> ischecked=RxList( [true,false,true]);`